# Como gerar PDF no PHP 7.0.30?

Tags: php

Bom dia, achei varios exemplos na internet de como gerar relatorio com `php` e `mysql`, só que nos exemplos todos usam o **php-5** e ao tentar fazer o mesmo com o **php-7.0.30** não consegui dá o erro `(HTTP ERROR 500)`.

Tentei usando a biblioteca **mPDF**(que já foi difícil de achar a versão 5.7 para baixar porque no site oficial não consegui baixar.

Então como gerar pdf com **`php 7.0.30?`**

Este é o codigo que estou usando:

```
<?php
include ('pdf/mpdf.php');

$pagina = 
        "<html>
            <body>
                <h2>Relatório de Profissionais S Network</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>teste</li>
                    <li>teste</li>
                    <li>teste</li>
                    <li>teste</li>
                </ul>
                <h4>Fonte: http://www.snetwork.com.br</h4>
            </body>
        </html>
        ";


$arquivo = "Profissionais01.php";

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);

$mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');


?>
```

> Obs: Não uso nenhum framework (laravel etc..) para desenvolver o sistema.

Comment: Chegaste a experimentar [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org)?

Comment: Difícil de baixar? Tentou [aqui](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf)? E eu creio que em qualquer versão da biblioteca,`$arquivo = "Profissionais01.php";` está errado. Passe um pdf para o nome do arquivo.

Comment: @lazyFox não testei o FPDF, ele funciona da mesma forma que o mPDF? qual a a diferença?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda para baixar pelo github apos baixar o zip como faço? "$arquivo = "Profissionais01.php"; está errado. Passe um pdf para o nome do arquivo." com assim ? coloco qual nome no arquivo?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda tem razão o seu output deverá ser um ficheiro `pdf` e não `php`. Invente um nome. @Mayke Alission o funcionamente irá ser diferente em cada uma das bibliotecas pois deverão ter implementações diferentes, mas vai dar tudo ao mesmo, apenas leia a [documentação](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm).

Comment: Baixando o pacote pelo `GitHub` vc descompacta e carrega na aplicação, como fez. No seu lugar, eu instalaria com o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), conforme a [documentação recomenda](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf#installation). Instalando com o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) fica mais seguro, pois ele instala todas as dependências da biblioteca. O correto é declarar uma extensão `.pdf`. Assim: `Profissionais01.pdf`.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda este sistema que estou criando e meu TCC que sera entregue na semana que vem, para usar o Composer terei que alterar alguma coisa no projeto? ou não mudara nada? pós não tenho tempo para reconfigurar as coisas.

Comment: Porque não usa a biblioteca DOMPDF?
Tutorial de como utilizar [AQUI](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7FRHiEEBWR2efigU-KM-8FeGhQ47htCG)

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar o DomPDF que é mais simples e funciona com o php 7+;

[Linkd para o DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Este é um exemplo simples de criação do PDF.

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```